# Devise ..After first login should ask for change password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using devise as authentication in my application.

I need to  implement feature in devise. After first login user should ask to change password.

I tried through model

```
 after_create :update_pass_change

    def update_pass_change
     self.pass_change = true
     self.save
    end
```

Comment: Redirect the user to change password page after first login

Comment: yes but having issue about routes. Could you tell me how to handle this condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checking `current_user.sign_in_count` is way to judge first login.

You'll do something like this.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if current_user.sign_in_count == 1
      edit_passwords_path
    else
      root_path
    end
  end
end
```

You need Implement edit/update password action.

```
class PasswordsController < ApplicationController
  def edit
  end

  def update
    if current_user.update_with_password(user_params)
      flash[:notice] = 'password update succeed..'
      render :edit
    else
      flash[:error] = 'password update failed.'
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:current_password, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

config/routes.rb

```
resource :passwords
```

app/views/passwords/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for current_user, url: passwords_path do |f| %>
  current_password:<br />
  <%= f.password_field :current_password %><br />
  password:<br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %><br />
  password_confirmation:<br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %><br />
  <br />
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I don't understand how this solution works because `edit_passwords_path` isn't a valid path for me and `edit_password_path` requires arguments.