# Force user to reset password on first login with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

[ETA updated at end with my current solution]

I want to be able to manually create accounts for high value users, which means we have to generate a password for them and get them to change it on first login. I found a solution to doing this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32395442/devise-after-first-login-should-ask-for-change-password), but it seems to work around Devise rather than with it.

My current effort is to overwrite the #after_confirmation_path_for method in the Devise ConfirmationsController so that it includes this snippet:

```
if resource.sign_in_count == 1
  resource.send(:set_reset_password_token)
  edit_password_path(resource, reset_password_token: @token)
else
  # etc
end
```

But when it follows the path, it redirects away from the password change, seemingly because of this line in the Devise::PasswordsController:

```
# Render the #edit only if coming from a reset password email link
append_before_filter :assert_reset_token_passed, only: :edit
```

So I could overwrite that call, but I'm wary about why it was there in the first place and whether that could cause other problems - even if not, it feels like I'm doing a lot of hacking to enable a scenario that I would imagine is relatively common. Is there a more Devise-y way to approach this?

ETA: I've made this successfully skip the filters with the following code:

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication,
                     :assert_reset_token_passed, 
                     only: :edit
end
```

This is working in the relevant user journey, but this is an app with relatively few acceptance tests, so I'm slightly wary this will have knock-on effects elsewhere - like unexpectedly requiring users to change their password in some other user journey.

Can anyone advise whether it's normal to use this approach, or is there a safer alternative?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29416605/1520965), it seems the answer to your question

Comment: We want to send them to the Devise password reset screen rather than direct them to the full profile edit.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue by signing out the user before redirecting, so that Devise can do its thing in peace. No other modification needed:

```rb
token = current_user.send(:set_reset_password_token)
sign_out(current_user)
redirect_to(edit_password_path(:user, reset_password_token: token))
```

Answer (score 2):

On your application controller, override the "after_sign_in_path" method.
use the sign_in_count to test if it's a first login :

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
 if current_user.sign_in_count == 1
  edit_passwords_path
 else
  root_path
 end
end
```

Comment: I'm successfully directing them to the edit_password_path, but the problem is then they're getting immediately redirected because (I think) of the `append_before_filter :assert_reset_token_passed, only: :edit` line. As things stand I think I can hack Devise to not redirect (although I haven't actually made that work yet, so maybe I speak too soon), but it feels like the sort of thing I'd expect Devise to have a more readymade solution for.